# Pivot Header Template Issue Windows Universal C# XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, pivot

I cant see my PivotItem, its invisible but the Binding is correctly:

My Template In App.xaml:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="GoldStyle">
        <ContentPresenter>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontFamily="Segoe Script" Foreground="Gold" FontSize="10"  Margin="0,70,0,0" />
        </ContentPresenter>
    </DataTemplate>
```

My Pivot:

```
<Pivot HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource GoldStyle}">
        <PivotItem Header="Public Profile"  >
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="-Set your Steam Profile to Public (Steam Settings)" FontFamily="Segoe Script" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="WhiteSmoke"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="Features">
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe Script" Text="-Calculate Price" Foreground="WhiteSmoke"></TextBlock>
        </PivotItem>
```

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first sight I thought that it was something weird, but the only issue is that in the TextBlock of the ContentPresenter you have Margin="0,70,0,0" replace to Margin="0,0,0,0".

All the other things are right.